# Very strange logarithm simplification

Tags: logarithms

I have very strange logarithm simplification:

$$\begin{array}{l}\frac{{{{\log }_{{2^{{{(x + 1)}^2}}} - 1}}({{\log }_{2{x^2} + 2x + 3}}({x^2} - 2x))}}{{{{\log }_{{2^{{{(x + 1)}^2}}} - 1}}({x^2} + 6x + 10)}} \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow {\log _{{x^2} + 6x + 10}}{\log _{2{x^2} + 2x + 3}}({x^2} - 2x) \ge 0\\\\when\,x \ne  - 3,x \ne  - 2,x \ne  - 1,x \ne 0\end{array}
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGceaqabeaadaWcaa
% qaaiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4zamaaBaaaleaacaaIYaWaaWbaaWqabeaa
% caGGOaGaamiEaiabgUcaRiaaigdacaGGPaWaaWbaaeqabaGaaGOmaa
% aaaaWccqGHsislcaaIXaaabeaakiaacIcaciGGSbGaai4BaiaacEga
% daWgaaWcbaGaaGOmaiaadIhadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaWccqGHRa
% WkcaaIYaGaamiEaiabgUcaRiaaiodaaeqaaOGaaiikaiaadIhadaah
% aaWcbeqaaiaaikdaaaGccqGHsislcaaIYaGaamiEaiaacMcacaGGPa
% aabaGaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWaaSbaaSqaaiaaikdadaahaaadbeqa
% aiaacIcacaWG4bGaey4kaSIaaGymaiaacMcadaahaaqabeaacaaIYa
% aaaaaaliabgkHiTiaaigdaaeqaaOGaaiikaiaadIhadaahaaWcbeqa
% aiaaikdaaaGccqGHRaWkcaaI2aGaaiiEaiabgUcaRiaaigdacaaIWa
% GaaiykaaaacqGHLjYScaaIWaGaeyi1HSTaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWa
% aSbaaSqaaiaadIhadaahaaadbeqaaiaaikdaaaWccqGHRaWkcaaI2a
% GaaiiEaiabgUcaRiaaigdacaaIWaaabeaakiGacYgacaGGVbGaai4z
% amaaBaaaleaacaaIYaGaamiEamaaCaaameqabaGaaGOmaaaaliabgU
% caRiaaikdacaWG4bGaey4kaSIaaG4maaqabaGccaGGOaGaamiEamaa
% CaaaleqabaGaaGOmaaaakiabgkHiTiaaikdacaWG4bGaaiykaiabgw
% MiZkaaicdaaeaaaeaacaGG3bGaaiiAaiaacwgacaGGUbGaaGPaVlaa
% cIhacqGHGjsUcqGHsislcaaIZaGaaiilaiaacIhacqGHGjsUcqGHsi
% slcaaIYaGaaiilaiaacIhacqGHGjsUcqGHsislcaaIXaGaaiilaiaa
% cIhacqGHGjsUcaaIWaaaaaa!9DAE!
$$

Is it valid?

For me it's the same as

$$\frac{{{{\log }_a}{{\log }_b}c}}{{{{\log }_a}d}} \ge 0 \Leftrightarrow {\log _d}{\log _b}c \ge 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaWaaSaaaeaaci
% GGSbGaai4BaiaacEgadaWgaaWcbaGaamyyaaqabaGcciGGSbGaai4B
% aiaacEgadaWgaaWcbaGaamOyaaqabaGccaWGJbaabaGaciiBaiaac+
% gacaGGNbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadggaaeqaaOGaamizaaaacqGHLjYScaaI
% WaGaeyi1HSTaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadsgaaeqaaO
% GaciiBaiaac+gacaGGNbWaaSbaaSqaaiaadkgaaeqaaOGaam4yaiab
% gwMiZkaaicdaaaa!53BC!
$$

I can't understand which rules leads to this simplification.

Comment: Why do you write $\Leftrightarrow$ between _numbers_? Tthat does not have any conventional meaning.

Comment: Sorry, I edited it.

Comment: $\log_a b = \frac{\log b}{\log a}$, apply to numerator and denominator, cancel $\log \bigl(2^{(x+1)^2}-1\bigr)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have
$$ \frac{\log_a \log_b c}{\log_a d} = \log_d \log_b c $$
by well known rule
$$ \log_d X = \frac{\log_a X}{\log_a d} $$
applied with $X=\log_b c$.

So the two expressions you're comparing to $0$ are *equal*, and so of course they are nonnegative at the same time.

---

You need more conditions than $x\notin\{-3,-2,-1,0\}$, though. In order for the logarithm of $x^2-2x$ to exist *and be positive*, we must have $x^2-2x>1$, which excludes the closed interval $[1-\sqrt2,1+\sqrt2]$.